# How do I make a list out of data derived from a dictionary?

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary:
data = {'John': 89, 'Sarah': 92, 'George': 79, 'Peter': 85, 'Pamela': 77}

I need to pull data from this dictionary, and create a list:
list = [89,92,79,85,77]

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
your_list = list(data.values())
# (don't use 'list' as the variable name
# since it's already a standard function)

print(your_list)
# [79, 77, 89, 92, 85]
```

One thing to keep in mind: dictionaries are unordered in Python, so you may need to sort the values if the order matters.

Comment: This is  exactly what I needed!  TYVM!